# SAS - Keeping only observations with all variables

Tags: sas, subset

I have a dataset of membership information, and I want to keep only the people who have been continuously enrolled for the entire year. There are 12 variables for each person, one for each month of the year with how many days during that month they were enrolled. Is there a way to make a subset of the data for just those with a value >1 for each of the month variables?

Thanks!

Comment: Show the code you've already tried, you're more likely to get a response - SO is not a code-on-demand service.

Comment: I'll be a little more specific than Chris, as I think the concept is perfectly fine to ask about, as this is an uncomplicated concept that doesn't exactly require lines and lines of code, but is asking about a concept itself (like "How do I make a font blue" in HTML, that's a fine if already-answered question).  However, to make a good question, include example data before AND after, and an example of the code that you're using other than the specific thing you're asking about, to make as clear as possible what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAS has various summary functions that might well be what you're looking for. See `min()` ([minimum](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000245915.htm)) in particular, as it will allow you to find the minimum of several variables. You may also want to consider `nmiss()` ([number of missing values](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000245920.htm)) and `n()` ([number of non-missing values](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000245918.htm)) if you have to deal with missing values in your data.

Summary functions can be passed lists of variables like this (in a data step):

```
minimum = min(var1, var2, var3);
```

However, that can become long winded if you need to use a lot of variables. Fortunately, SAS provides several ways to reference lists of variables to make things neater. You can read about these [variable lists here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000695105.htm). To use them in a summary function use the `of` qualifier:

```
minimum = min(of var1-var12);
maximum = max(of var:);
blanks = nmiss(of _NUMERIC_);
```

Finally you will want to use your new found data to decide whether what data to include. To do this in a data step look at the `output` statement ([user guide](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/63323/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1lltvbis7ye1an1eryo4leh2mck.htm)):

```
if min(of var:) > 1 then output;
```

Or if you feel like learning a bit more about SAS's syntax you could try using an implicit output by reading through the last link.

<s>In general it's preferred to ask specific questions and show your current work on SO, and I'd advise using google to answer your basic questions while you're learning the fundamentals. There is plenty of great documentation available to help you out there.</s>

Comment: Just to clarify, there's no prohibition or even preference against asking basic questions on StackOverflow; questions at all levels are encouraged, so long as they are sufficiently specific to be understandable and answerable.