# Keep only observations with data for all variables

Tags: subset, stata, sample, missing-data

I have a dataset with several variables. I want to create a subsample which only includes the observations which have data for all variables, so no missing data in any of the variable.

I know about the `dropmiss` command in Stata but that does not apply here because I do not want to drop variables, but I want to drop the observations.

I found a question similar to mine in Stack Overflow, but the statistical program used there is SAS and I am using Stata. 
 ([SAS - Keeping only observations with all variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614514/sas-keeping-only-observations-with-all-variables)).

An example (the "." is a missing data):

```
ID year pension age gender
1  2006 300    54   F
2  2007 250    40   M
3  2006  .     45   M
4  2005  .      .   F
```

So in this case I only want to keep ID 1 and 2, and `drop` 3 and 4 from the sample since it contains missing data for some of the variables.

Answer (score 2):

The statement about `dropmiss` (download from *Stata Journal* website after `search dropmiss`) is incorrect.

`dropmiss` has an `obs` option geared to this need.

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. dropmiss, obs
(0 observations deleted)

. dropmiss, obs any
(5 observations deleted)
```

However, `dropmiss` is considered by its author (that's me) to be superseded by `missings` (download similarly from *Stata Journal* website). `missings` doesn't support this directly, as considering whether missing values can be handled by multiple imputation is widely considered better statistical practice.

But if you insist, `missings` can help with this too:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. missings tag, gen(anymiss)

Checking missings in all variables:
5 observations with missing values

. drop if anymiss
(5 observations deleted)
```

There's an `egen` function `rowmiss()` that behaves similarly.

What's key here is that you don't need to spell out the variable names concerned. However, watch out: these commands can be highly destructive.

Comment: nick thanks for the clarification but I hope I am getting the answer though!

Comment: If you mean which answer is accepted, that's clearly out of my control. If a user had a thousand variables, they wouldn't want to type all their names.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty simple assuming you have a limited number of variables.
Just type:

```
keep if !missing(var1) & !missing(var2) & !missing(var3)
```

That command will only keep **rows** that have non-missing values of all of the three variables mentioned above. Feel free to add more.

Comment: `keep if !missing(var1, var2, var3)` has the same effect.